# Getting error when subscribing to promise

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am getting an error when page is getting loaded saying

```
people.ts?9320:22 SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
<(…)PeopleComponent.apiService.people.subscribe.error @ people.ts?
9320:22SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ VM38600:166SafeSubscriber.error @ 
VM38600:127Subscriber._error @ VM38600:77Subscriber.error @ 
VM38600:57MapSubscriber._next @ VM38955:51Subscriber.next @ 
VM38600:51onLoad @ VM38808:57ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ 
VM38526:423NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask @ 
VM38628:36ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ VM38526:422Zone.runTask @ 
VM38526:320ZoneTask.invoke @ VM38526:490
```

Here is my code:

```
export class PeopleComponent {
    people: any;
    constructor(apiService: Api) {
        apiService.people
            .subscribe({
                next: x => (this.people = x),
                error: e => console.error(e), //error line 22 is here!
                complete: () => console.log('Completed!')
            });
    }
}
```

My Api sevice:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class Api {
  people: any;

  constructor(http: Http) {
    this.people = http.get(require('./people.json'))
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you include `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/Rx.js"></script>`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it is included through webpack

Comment: Looks like one of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+%22unexpected+token+%3C%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to subscribe this way:

```
apiService.people
      .subscribe(
        x => {this.people = x;},
        e => {console.error(e);},
        () => {console.log('Completed!');}
      });
```

See this documentation:

- https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

Comment: Any more thoughts?

Comment: Could you tell me more about what you use in your project? Do you use TypeScript or ES6? If using TypeScript how do you compile your code? Thanks!

Comment: I am using TypeScript

Comment: I just saw that you use a `require` at the level of your service. Seems strange. You should use this: https://plnkr.co/edit/ESkRoqXt2fmnFdCjiDzp?p=preview.

Comment: Yeah probably I have issues with that which is giving an error. It is what I am currently explore

Comment: I just decided to replace the file with the real http request to see the difference but fall in to another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714525/exception-no-provider-for-headers-app-api-headers